# How to add a button to go to new activity in android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a 'button' that leads to a new activity inside of my main activity of my app. I cannot get this button to respond inside of this main activity. I tried to put the following in my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private ImageView photoImageView;
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView emailTextView;
    private TextView idTextView;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        photoImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        idTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTextView);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();



// I want something like this - click a textView to go to the new activity

        TextView listViewItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        listViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
// end



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**How can I get this button to go to my new activity? I am using a text view as a button currently. Is this my problem?**

```
 <LinearLayout
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:text="One"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="70dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is button?? put your xml code and image

Comment: I edited and posted the important bit of my xml @VishvaDave

Comment: Is there any error log? And this textview is inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: This textview is in activity_main. @VishvaDave

Comment: It seems perfect actually :D

Comment: you need to learn about Intent. Google it how to redirect to a page using INTENT activity.

Comment: You can try by implementing the on click listner. may be this listner is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="text";
     android:textSize="28sp" />
```

Comment: The button is fine. I can see it on my app. I want to click it to go to a new activity